# What happens, and how quickly, to the old container when I do a docker stack deploy --prune

Tags: docker, deployment

We're doing deployments with `docker swarm deploy --prune ...` and having great success for the most part, *but* I have questions that I can't find answers to around what exactly `--prune` does.

I know it removes the old services, but I have questions about:

- *when* does it remove the old services?
- *how* does it remove the old services?

So for example, say Apache is running in the *old* container, and we do a `docker stack deploy --prune ...`.

Does Apache just get `kill -KILL`d? Does it run `apachectl stop`?

When does that happen? At some specific # of minutes after the deploy, or...?

If I have a long-running HTTP request (e.g. say it's a download being streamed to a user, and it's 100gb, and takes 15 minutes to stream), does pruning the image just forcibly stop Apache and kill that download? Or will it wait until the download finishes, and exit cleanly?

Comment: I would expect standard `docker stop` behaviour, sending `SIGTERM` followed by `SIGKILL` after a grace period (I think the default is 10 seconds).